# Which Angular module creates (click) DOM attibute and handles DOM click events?

Tags: html, angular, events, attributes

When user want to add click event handling to Angular's based app, one adds

```
(click)="someFunction()"
```

to some html element.

What part of [core] Angular module code is responsible for creating this event binding and handling it?
Was searching for the answer through Angular 5.x code and didn't found any line which could clearly state that it's for creating and handling (click) event binding.

Answer (score 4):

There is no module for that. When Angulars template parser parses that markup it creates internal data structures to represent that and then creates TypeScript code for it that is then transpiled to JavaScript.

At runtime there won't be a `(click)="..."` or similar Angular specific markup except when the [platform-browser-dynamic](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic) module is used to compile Angular components at runtime.

Comment: Correct !!! but still OP is asking about the source code that will come into picture at run-time written in Typescript if I'm not wrong.

Comment: The template parser is doing that. Here are the strings for event bindings https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/86d96122305087626fbb5ae94e38ff9082a2a083/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L50-L56 and here they are usd https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/86d96122305087626fbb5ae94e38ff9082a2a083/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L482

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the Angular  “event binding” using the target event (in your example the click event of the ‘HTML element like button  ‘. 
You can setup breakpoint if you want observe the part of the code that gets triggered. Maybe use firebug or other add-ons in your favourite browser. 
Some background info here (event binding section ) 
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding